# Recreate a Deleted Channel with The Same Properties (Discord.js v11)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm coding a channel protection system for my Discord Bot.
we use the code channel.clone to reopen deleted channels one-on-one. Although this code works spectacularly on text channels, it does not work well in audio channels. I need a code to open the audio channels the same way.
also, when a category is deleted, I don't know how to move channels in the deleted category to the new category.

the code I currently use to reopen the channel:

```
client.on('channelDelete', (channel) => {
  channel.clone()
    .then((clone) => {
        console.log(`Cloned ${channel.name} to make a channel called ${clone.name}`);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

Discord.js Version: v11.6.4

Comment: Can you give more details on what exactly doesn't work when cloning audio channels? Also, you can use `channel.setParent(categoryID)` to set the category of a channel.

Comment: Error Cloning Audio Channel: https://i.hizliresim.com/53olOO.png
I know how to categorize a channel, what I can't find; Automatically Find Channels in Old Category and Add them to New Category.
(I Use Google Translate, It May Be Misspelling)

Comment: From the error, it looks as if you are providing an invalid option when cloning the channel. Try passing an options object to the `channel.clone()` for example `channel.clone({bitrate: 8000})`

Comment: it worked! thank you for your help. But I do not know how to add channels that are in the deleted category to the new category :c

Comment: Can you not just do `channel.setParent(categoryID)`

Comment: How can I find what's in the content of the old category?

Comment: `category.children` will return a collection of all the channels in that category